# How can I draw custom shapes on object to be deformed?

Tags: mesh, transforms

There is a imported STL object. How can I draw custom mesh or grid on surface of object?
I need two areas of shape ,  the first one is to define deformation range (like blue area in picture);the other one is for stretch or transformation (like red area in picture).
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In sculpt mode, you can draw a mask like this:

[image]

Then smooth the mask using Mask → Smooth Mask

Add iterations using <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

Then Invert mask (Mask → Invert Mask) and make an operation for example grab like this:

[image]